# Can you use two weapon fighting on a bonus action after casting a spell with war caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, two-weapon-fighting

As a cleric I have two weapon fighting and I took the war caster feat. I was wondering if I could cast a spell as an action and then make a melee attack as a bonus action?

Comment: To be clear: are you talking about the Fighting Style "two-weapon fighting" (typically an option for martial classes), or the regular two-weapon fighting (PHB 195) available to anyone? (Also, I'm not sure why War Caster would matter?)

Comment: You could improve this question by clarifying why you believe war caster affects this interaction, preferably by citing the rules/features that you're focused on and highlighting which parts of them you want to know interact.

Answer (score 12):

### Two Weapon Fighting requires the Attack action, but you took the Cast a Spell action.

Two Weapon Fighting states:

> When you take the **Attack** action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand.

You took the **Cast a Spell** action, but Two Weapon Fighting requires the **Attack** action. No feature of War Caster changes this, and it isn’t particularly clear what part of War Caster you think may change this.

Comment: +1, beat me to it. In addition, I was going to point out that a bonus action can only be taken on your own turn, and even if enemy movement happened on your turn and provoked an Op Attack then, a reaction can't fulfill the requirements of using an action. I suspect they were looking at War Caster for the interaction provided with Booming Blade or Green-flame Blade as an Op Attack and thinking they could get a second swing from it.  Might be worthwhile for them to explore an Eldritch Knight's War Magic feature, though.

Comment: The part of war caster that states you have a weapon in one or both hands.

Comment: @DstrbdSuperman That part of War Caster has to do with a different rules situation restricting the casting of spells that have Somatic Components without a Material Component. As an example, the shield spell cannot normally be cast while wielding a staff with a mundane shield- in order to use the staff to cast the spell, the spell would require a material component with the Somatic, which it lacks. War Caster allows you to ignore the requirement of a free hand for such spells.